# Can I share a character across devices

Tags: kingdom-hearts-unchained-x

I have an Android phone, and an iPad and I have Unchained X installed on both. But when I start a new game, it starts a new character on each device and I track them separately. Is there a way to share a character between the devices? Or at least share progress or something?